# Controller to get and return an RSS XML file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I've been asked to wrap an RSS request into an ASP.NET WebAPI controller. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437731/create-rss-feed-in-mvc4-webapi

Comment: I'm not looking to create an RSS feed, I just need to pass through the XML file for an RSS feed.

Comment: i am still not clear...do you mean you would be passing the RSS feed xml to an Api controller action and would want that to be deserialized in some format?

Comment: Reasons are convoluted but I have no say in the matter. I need to get the XML returned from an RSS call and return it intact. I imagine this can be done in the controller action as it does not require any models.

Comment: Is there a a name for people who drive-by downvote without leaving a comment as to what it is they didn't like? I mean, I know what I call them privately, but there has to be a more politically correct name for the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you could do something like below:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(<Stream having xml content>);
    // or
    //response.Content = new StringContent("string having xml content");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/rss+xml");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: How do you create the Stream with the XML file's contents?